# Add alt text to img tag using c#

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to update `alt` attribute text to `<img>` tag in c# behind, have no idea to do so.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<img id="DetailsImage" runat="server" alt="" class="DetailsImage" />
```

In aspx.cs

```
DetailsImage.Src = dsArticleDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageURL"].ToString();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `Alt` property?

Comment: I wanted to add from code behind

Comment: Yes. In code behind... (You should get `HtmlImage` object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you should use `Alt` property.

```
DetailsImage.Alt = "My alternate text"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AttributeCollection. Also using this you can change, add all attributes of all html element

```
DetailsImage.Attributes.Add("alt","what you want");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DetailsImage.Alt?